# What are some other methods for partitioning an n-dimensional space based on a set of points in that space?

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, tiling, triangulations, planar-partitions

So this is a very general question, but I'm curious if there are any other methods for partitioning an n-dimensional space based on the location of a set of points, either randomly chosen or specified, within that space.

Voronoi tessellation and Delaunay triangulation are the go-to examples I have in mind, and in general, what I am looking for is a comprehensive list of methods in existing literature for polygonal tessellation of the plane (or polytopal tesselations of higher-dimensional spaces) with some sort of relationship between the polygons(topes) and the specified points.

Such a method should produce a result with no intersecting lines, but otherwise, my requirements are very loose and mostly driven by curiosity. Thanks!